# Angular 4 aux routing

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Хочу очистить url после aux роутинга с

```
http://localhost:4200/(popup:login)
```

в

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

использую

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: null } }]"
```

Но это не помогает очистить url и привести его к форме ниже. Хотя ошибки не выдаются

```
 http://localhost:4200/
```

Я использую Angular 4.1.3 CLI
 routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch:'full', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'login', outlet:'popup', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'register', outlet:'popup', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Создаю aux роут вешая на ссылку

```
[routerLink]="[{outlets: {popup: ['login']}}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас же 2 router-outlet (один основной, и второй - popup), поэтому:

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'login',  popup: null } }]"
```